# What does a production chart actually show?

Tags: the-first-alkahistorian-stage-3

Stage 3 of The First Alkahistorian has a "Production Chart" for each recipe, that looks like a pie chart with various shades of gray, but as far as I can tell there's no legend or any other indication of what each slice indicates.
Here are a few examples:

[image: Screenshot of a production chart from The First Alkahistorian]

What is this chart trying to show me?

Answer (score 3):

- Light Grey = couldn't do recipe due to max storage
- Grey = performed the recipe
- Dark Grey = couldn't do recipe due to lack of ingredients
- Black = recipe never turned on before

Source: playing the game for numerous complete play-throughs